# Invalid Command name "" error

Tags: tcl

A tcl script I've been using for a while to extract vectors has suddenly stopped working, and I'm unsure as to why. In addition, the error doesn't appear to make sense either.

The code I'm running is:

```
for {set resd 501} {$resd < 502} {incr resd 1} {
set basefile1 "CCvector$resd"

set workdir [pwd]
set nf [molinfo top get numframes]

set fil [open $basefile1.dat w]

for {set frame 0} {$frame < $nf} {incr frame 1} {
    animate goto $frame
    display update ui
    set c1 [atomselect top "name C1 and resid $resd and resname G130"]
    set c3 [atomselect top "name C3 and resid $resd and resname G130"]
    set c1c [$c1 get {x y z} ]
    set c3c [$c3 get {x y z} ]
    set c1c3x [expr [$c3 get x]-[$c1 get x]]
    set c1c3y [expr [$c3 get y]-[$c1 get y]]
    set c1c3z [expr [$c3 get z]-[$c1 get z]]
    set st [expr $frame]
    puts $fil [list $st $c1c3x $c1c3y $c1c3z ]
    $c3 delete
    $c1 delete 
}
close $fil
```

The original error I was receiving was "Missing operand at *@*", however I replaced portions of the code to become:

```
for {set frame 0} {$frame < $nf} {incr frame 1} {
    animate goto $frame
    display update ui
    set c1 [atomselect top "name C1 and resid $resd and resname G130"]
    set c3 [atomselect top "name C3 and resid $resd and resname G130"]
    set c1x [$c1 get x]
    set c3x [$c3 get x]
    set c1c3x [expr [$c3x - $c1x]]
    set c1y [$c1 get y]
    set c3y [$c3 get y]
    set c1c3y [expr [$c3y - $c1y]]
    set c1z [$c1 get z]
    set c3z [$c3 get z]
    set c1c3z [expr [$c3z - $c1z]]
    set st [expr $frame]
    puts $fil [list $st $c1c3x $c1c3y $c1c3z ]
    $c3 delete
    $c1 delete 
}
close $fil
```

and am now receiving an "Invalid Command Name "" " error instead. Where am I going wrong?

Additional info: I'm running this using VMD to extract the coordinates from a gromacs trajectory loaded in.

Answer (score 3):

In:

```
set c1c3z [expr [$c3z - $c1z]]
```

You'd trying to run the `$c3z` command with `-` and the content of `$c1z` as arguments (and pass its return value as an argument to `expr`).

To be equivalent to the previous version of the code, it would be:

```
set c1c3z [expr $c3z - $c1z]
```

However, since `$c3z` seems to be empty (so not a number), you possibly have more problems.

Here, with `$c3z` and `$c1z` being most likely empty, that means `expr` evaluates the `" - "` expression and you'll be back to seeing a:

```
$ tclsh <<< 'expr " - "'
missing operand at _@_
in expression " - _@_"
```

If as suggested by Donal in comments, you wrote instead:

```
set c1c3z [expr {$c3z - $c1z}]
```

instead, then a literal `$c3z - $c1z` would be passed to `expr` and `expr` would be able to give you a more useful error message as it tries to evaluate it:

```
$ tclsh <<< 'set a ""; expr {$a - $a}'
can't use empty string as operand of "-"
```

The [`expr` TCL man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm) will give you more information as to why it's generally preferable to pass `{}`-enclosed expressions to it.

Comment: Even better would be `set c1c3z [expr {$c3z - $c1z}]` as that avoids all sorts of trouble and enables higher-speed compilation.